# Django - Adding a prefix when using reverse()

Tags: django, reverse

Is it possible to have a prefix when using the reverse function?

for example:
I have reverse('foo') that point to www.bla.com/foo

but the URL needs to be www.bla.com/bla2/foo

So the bla2 would be the prefix

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If '/bla2' is the mount point for your Django application, with a correctly setup WSGI server you should not need to do anything to add it. This is because the WSGI server should already be sending through `SCRIPT_NAME` set as '/bla2' and Django should insert that automatically at the front of URLs constructed using reverse().

Can you explain what WSGI server you are using and/or whether you have it hosted behind a proxy front end that is publishing the site at a different URL mount point to the backend.

If you do have this situation where a front end is proxying as '/bla2', but the backend has it mounted at '/'. Then the Django setting you need to specify to force the backend to use '/bla2' and so insert the correct prefix is `FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME`.

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#force-script-name

Note that this affects the whole site.

Comment: The FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME was exactly what I was looking for. But for some links it works and for others don't. I believe that's because sometimes the server grab the all URL and other times the server just append the /bla2 at the end of URL so www.bla.com/bla2/bla2/foo is the final URL. Do you know where I can set to the server grab all the URL and not just append? This problem only happens with the reverse() function. When I set the path manually like <a href='/foo'> instead of reverse('foo') goes normally

Comment: You sure you aren't hardwiring the mount point anywhere in your code or urls.py.

Answer (score 0):

if you need `www.bla.com/bla2/foo` then your `foo` url should be pointing to `www.bla.com/bla2/foo` not `www.bla.com/foo`

Other way to perform that, is creating a final url, something like this:

```
final_url = prefix + reverse('foo')
```

Note:
`reverse('foo')` will output `/foo/` not `www.bla.com/foo`